# Opening a Document from Visio with a SelectionAdded Event

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to make a shape object in Visio (2013 or later) open a local document through VBA when selected.

I have tried using the code below to get the event to create a msgbox thinking I would later change the msgbox functionality out to open a document but the msgbox won't display when I select a shape.

```
Private WithEvents OrgChartApp As Visio.Application

Private Sub OrgChartApp_SelectionAdded(ByVal Selection As IVSelection)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there code where you set OrgChartApp = Visio.Application?  I'm not sure what module this code is residing in but if it's in ThisDocument then Document_DocumentOpened, or if it's in a class then in Class_Initialize or if i'ts in a form then in UserForm_Initialize.  Anyway I'm assuming the problem is that the OrgChartApp is not set to anything, since there's no code showing that it is set.

Comment: @JonFournier This was the problem, thanks!